# Help with squid proxy on VPS

Tags: proxy, centos, squid

I've spent the past 2 days attempt an install of squid caching proxy on my hostgator vps.

I've gotten all the way up to the point where I turn the squid service on and always end up with the same issue "ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied" in the squid log.

Here is the log from squid itself:

```
2010/04/20 16:12:58| helperOpenServers: Starting 5/5 'ncsa_auth' processes
2010/04/20 16:12:58| ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied
2010/04/20 16:12:58| ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied
2010/04/20 16:12:58| ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied
2010/04/20 16:12:58| ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied
2010/04/20 16:12:58| ipcCreate: /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth: (13) Permission denied
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 22
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Store logging disabled
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Target number of buckets: 1008
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Using 8192 Store buckets
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Using Least Load store dir selection
2010/04/20 16:12:58| chdir: /usr/local/squid/var/cache: (2) No such file or directory
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Current Directory is /usr/src
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Loaded Icons.
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Accepting  HTTP connections at [::]:8854, FD 23.
2010/04/20 16:12:58| HTCP Disabled.
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Squid modules loaded: 0
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Ready to serve requests.
2010/04/20 16:12:58| WARNING: basicauthenticator #5 (FD 16) exited
2010/04/20 16:12:58| WARNING: basicauthenticator #4 (FD 14) exited
2010/04/20 16:12:58| WARNING: basicauthenticator #3 (FD 12) exited
2010/04/20 16:12:58| WARNING: basicauthenticator #2 (FD 10) exited
2010/04/20 16:12:58| Too few basicauthenticator processes are running
2010/04/20 16:12:58| storeDirWriteCleanLogs: Starting...
2010/04/20 16:12:58|   Finished.  Wrote 0 entries.
2010/04/20 16:12:58|   Took 0.00 seconds (  0.00 entries/sec).
FATAL: The basicauthenticator helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!

Squid Cache (Version 3.1.1): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.018 seconds = 0.007 user + 0.011 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 0 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
        total space in arena:    3164 KB
        Ordinary blocks:         3042 KB      8 blks
        Small blocks:               0 KB      0 blks
        Holding blocks:          1680 KB      7 blks
        Free Small blocks:          0 KB
        Free Ordinary blocks:     121 KB
        Total in use:            4722 KB 149%
        Total free:               121 KB 4%
```

I am logged in as root when I attempt to load squid.

Server is running CentOS 5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have it configure to only allow access through an ncsa login.

** I'm running the latest compiled version of squid proxy v3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I know squid setup can be quite daunting as I myself had to do it before. Have you taken a look at "varnish"? It has an easier setup and may be easier to install.